# Webpack Hot module replacement, react 18 ReactDOMClient.createRoot() on a container that has already been passed to createRoot() before

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I updated React to v18 and my Webpack dev server gives me a console error whenever the hot module replacement fires and injects the new javascript code:

`Warning: You are calling ReactDOMClient.createRoot() on a container that has already been passed to createRoot() before. Instead, call root. render() on the existing root instead if you want to update it.`

`index.js` file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App.jsx';

const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container);

root.render(<App />);

if (module.hot) module.hot.accept(function (err) {
    console.log('An error occurred while accepting new version');
});
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWEbpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = (env) => {
  let cfg = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      filename: 'bundle.[contenthash:6].js',
      publicPath: '/',
      clean: true
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader'
          }
        },
      ]
    },
    plugins: [new HtmlWEbpackPlugin({ template: './src/index.html' })
    ],
    devServer: {
      static: {
        directory: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
      },
      compress: true,
      port: 3000,
      hot: true,
      open: true,
      
    },
    performance: {
      hints: false
    }

  }

  return cfg;
};
```

Answer (score 19):

React 18 has native support for hot reloading, this is called Fast Refresh. An excerpt from the [react-refresh](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/main/packages/react-refresh) readme:

*Fast Refresh is a feature that lets you edit React components in a running application without losing their state. It is similar to an old feature known as "hot reloading", but Fast Refresh is more reliable and officially supported by React.*

To use this with Webpack 5, you will need a plugin called [react-refresh-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin). To get it to work I would recommend taking a look at the examples included in the git repository, especially the [webpack-dev-server](https://github.com/pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/tree/main/examples/webpack-dev-server) example.

**NOTE:** As of writing this answer, the `react-refresh-webpack-plugin` is in an experimental state but `create-react-app` is already using it, so it is probably stable enough to use.

The following is taken straight from `react-refresh-webpack-plugin`'s `webpack-dev-server` example:

`src/index.js`

```js
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';

const container = document.getElementById('app');
const root = createRoot(container);
root.render(<App />);
```

`webpack.config.js`

```js
const path = require('path');
const ReactRefreshPlugin = require('@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

module.exports = {
  mode: isDevelopment ? 'development' : 'production',
  devServer: {
    client: { overlay: false },
  },
  entry: {
    main: './src/index.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        use: 'babel-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    isDevelopment && new ReactRefreshPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: './index.html',
      template: './public/index.html',
    }),
  ].filter(Boolean),
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
};
```

`babel.config.js`

```js
module.exports = (api) => {
  // This caches the Babel config
  api.cache.using(() => process.env.NODE_ENV);
  return {
    presets: [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      // Enable development transform of React with new automatic runtime
      ['@babel/preset-react', { development: !api.env('production'), runtime: 'automatic' }],
    ],
    // Applies the react-refresh Babel plugin on non-production modes only
    ...(!api.env('production') && { plugins: ['react-refresh/babel'] }),
  };
};
```

You can remove the following from your Webpack entry point:

`src/index.js`

```js
// ...
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept()
}
```

This has the small drawback that whenever you modify your entry point (`src/index.js`) a full reload is necessary. Webpack is very in your face about needing to do a full reload, showing you the following log messages.

[image: [image]]

This really annoyed me. When looking at how [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) solved this, I found that they disabled client side logging for the `webpack-dev-server`, or at least set the log level to `warn` or `error`. You can set the log level by setting the `client.logging` property in the `devServer` configuration:

`webpack.config.js`

```js
// ...
devServer: {
  client: {
    overlay: false,
    logging: 'warn' // Want to set this to 'warn' or 'error'
  }
}
// ...
```

What the odd thing is about the "warning", is that it is not a warning at all, it is just an info message dressed up as a warning.

Hope this helps.