# React-Router-Dom-v6 component doesn't render when page is refreshed, receiving state from contextApi

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm building a simple application to study ContextAPI and react-router, using react-router-dom-v6 for it.

The application works perfectly in the normal data flow, I have a list of teams, click on a team, and it renders the Team component with it's members.
But if I try to refresh the Team component page, it gets an error, I have to go back to the teams list, and click on the team again to it works.

My RoutesTree:

```
        <AppContext.Provider value={value}>
            <Routes>
                <Route path={'/'} element={<App />} />
                <Route path='/teams/:id' element={<Team />} />
            </Routes>
        </AppContext.Provider>
```

in my Teams List component:

```
            <TeamsList>
                {currentTeams.map((team, index) => {
                    return (
                        <Link
                            key={index}
                            to={`/teams/${team.id}`}
                        >
                            <TeamCard
                                teamName={team.name}
                            />
                        </Link>
                    )
                })}
            </TeamsList>
```

my Team component:

```
const Team = () => {
    const { id } = useParams();
    const { state, setState } = useContext(AppContext);
    const [team, setTeam] = useState(undefined)

    const [teamMembers, setTeamMembers] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getTeam = async () => {
            const response = await axios.get(`${teamsApiUrl}/${id}`);
            setTeam(response.data);
        };

        getTeam();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (team) {
            const lead = state.users.find((user) => user.id === team.teamLeadId);
            const members = state.users.filter((user) => team.teamMemberIds.includes(user.id));
            setTeamMembers([lead, ...members]);
        }
    }, [team]);

    return (
        <>
            {team && <div>
                <div>Team: {team.name}</div>
                <div>
                    <span>Members:</span>
                    {teamMembers.map((member, index) => {
                        if (index === 0) {
                            return (
                                <div key={index}>Team Lead: {member.displayName}</div>
                            );
                        } else {
                            return (
                                <div key={index}>{member.displayName}</div>
                            );
                        }
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>}
            <Link to='/'>Teams List</Link>
        </>
    );

}
```

The error log on the browser (**if I update anything on the code**)

```
[HMR] Checking for updates on the server... log.js:24:12
[HMR] Cannot apply update. Need to do a full reload! log.js:26:12
[HMR] Aborted because ./src/components/Team/Team.js is not accepted
Update propagation: ./src/components/Team/Team.js -> ./src/components/RoutesTree/RoutesTree.js -> ./src/index.js
applyHandler@http://localhost:8080/main.js:2074:31
internalApply/results<@http://localhost:8080/main.js:1773:21
internalApply@http://localhost:8080/main.js:1772:54
hotCheck/</</</<@http://localhost:8080/main.js:1742:26
waitForBlockingPromises@http://localhost:8080/main.js:1696:48
hotCheck/</</<@http://localhost:8080/main.js:1740:24
promise callback*hotCheck/</<@http://localhost:8080/main.js:1739:18
promise callback*hotCheck/<@http://localhost:8080/main.js:1719:43
promise callback*hotCheck@http://localhost:8080/main.js:1710:15
check@webpack://ecore-project/./node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js?:14:5
@webpack://ecore-project/./node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js?:55:4
emit@webpack://ecore-project/./node_modules/events/events.js?:153:17
reloadApp@webpack://ecore-project/./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/utils/reloadApp.js?:53:67
ok@webpack://ecore-project/./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?:187:68
initSocket/<@webpack://ecore-project/./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/socket.js?:68:29
onMessage/this.client.onmessage@webpack://ecore-project/./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/clients/WebSocketClient.js?:55:10
EventHandlerNonNull*onMessage@webpack://ecore-project/./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/clients/WebSocketClient.js?:54:7
initSocket@webpack://ecore-project/./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/socket.js?:60:10
@webpack://ecore-project/./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?:287:55
./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?protocol=ws%3A&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=8080&pathname=%2Fws&logging=info&reconnect=10@http://localhost:8080/main.js:948:1
__webpack_require__@http://localhost:8080/main.js:1313:33
@http://localhost:8080/main.js:2401:30
@http://localhost:8080/main.js:2405:12
```

If I **just refresh** the page, it gets a different error: (I translated the error from Portuguese to English, might not be the exact message that the browser would give in english)

```
GEThttp://localhost:8080/teams/main.js
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 2ms]

The resource of “http://localhost:8080/teams/main.js” was blocked due to type MIME (“text/html”) doesn't match (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
83e58f56-0ecf-4ea9-bdff-81ded3342061
Failure to load <script> with resource “http://localhost:8080/teams/main.js”.
```

I don't know if the issue is with the react-router or with webpack.. I'm new on using both of them

Update: Webpack configurations are the following:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
    template: './src/index.html',
    filename: './index.html'
});

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        static: './',
        hot: true
    },
    plugins: [htmlPlugin]
};
```

Comment: Issues with routing upon page reloads is ***almost always*** a server issue and/or webpack issue. `react-router` just reads the path from the URL, ***but*** your React app running from the "root" directory needs to load first in order to do this. The server should redirect page requests for nested pages to the directory where the app is running. I see you are running locally, but how exactly are you running your React app?

Comment: @DrewReese I'm using webpack to run the React App, will add the webpack configurations to the post!

Comment: I've also tried the configurations from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71719220/webpack-hot-module-replacement-react-18-reactdomclient-createroot-on-a-contai , but no success

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue after researching a lot on it.
It seems the issue was with Webpack hot reload and using React 18.

What I did:
installed

```
npm install @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin react-refresh -D
```

created a babel.config.js file:

```
module.exports = (api) => {
    // This caches the Babel config
    api.cache.using(() => process.env.NODE_ENV);
    return {
        presets: [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            // Enable development transform of React with new automatic runtime
            ['@babel/preset-react', { development: !api.env('production'), runtime: 'automatic' }],
        ],
        // Applies the react-refresh Babel plugin on non-production modes only
        ...(!api.env('production') && { plugins: ['react-refresh/babel'] }),
    };
};
```

on my webpack.config.js:

```
const ReactRefreshPlugin = require('@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin');
...
        rules: [
            {
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        plugins: [require.resolve('react-refresh/babel')]
                    }
                }
                }
            },
            },
...
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        static: './',
        static: './',
        hot: true
        hot: true,
        open: true,
        client: {
            overlay: false,
            logging: 'warn'
        }
    },
    },
    plugins: [htmlPlugin]
    plugins: [
        new ReactRefreshPlugin(),
        htmlPlugin
    ]
```

and added this  to index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<html lang="en">
    <base href="/" />
```